# D3 js - line not showing in real time line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, line, real-time

I am creating an application which works with a bluetooth heart rate monitor, and I will be using D3.js to graph the heart rate in real time. Currently, I'm just creating a simple example which I can tweak later to work with real data.

Basically all I am trying to do at this stage is plot randomly generated data over the last minute. The data, readings, is an array of dummy readings of the form `{timestamp: (the time which it was generated), hr:(num between 0 and 1)}`. Initially readings will be empty but every second, a new random value with the current time will be pushed on.

For some reason, the graph isn't showing, however there are no errors being reported in my code. The x-axis seems to be correct and transitioning fine. Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

I am going to post my entire code as I am not sure of the origin of the issue.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>
    <svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    var n = 40,
        random = d3.randomUniform(0, 1),
        readings = [],
        currentReadings = [],
        duration = 1000,
        now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);
        startTime = new Date();
    
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([now - 60000, now])
        .range([0, width]);
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(data) { return xScale(data.time); })
        .y(function(data) { return yScale(data.hr); })
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);
    
    g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    
    var xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).
          ticks(3));
    
    var yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    
    var path = g.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("path")
        .datum(currentReadings)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .on("start", tick);
    
    
    function tick() {

        now = new Date();
        
        // update the x axis domain and slide left
        xScale.domain([now - 60000, now]);
        xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
        
        // generate new random reading
        reading = {time: new Date(), hr: random()};
    
        // Push the new reading onto readings and currentReadings
        readings.push(reading);
        currentReadings.push(reading);

        // Remove readings not within graph period
        for (var i=0; i<currentReadings.length; i++) {
          if (now - currentReadings[i].time > 60000)
            currentReadings.shift();
          else
            break;
        }
    
        // Redraw the line.
        d3.select(this)
            .datum(currentReadings)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("transform", null);
    
        // Slide it to the left.
        d3.active(this)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(0) + ",0)")
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .on("start", tick);
    
    }
    
    
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue is that you are translating the graph too much. It is drawing, just not anywhere remotely visible. Why?

```
   d3.active(this)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(0) + ",0)")
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .on("start", tick);
```

You are translating by xScale(0), which is some very high magnitude negative number:

```js
var now = new Date();

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([now - 60000, now])
  .range([0, 100]);
        
        
console.log(xScale(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So you'll never see your graph, it's well to the left. Instead, you could translate by the difference in x values between coordinates (as you update once per second, and show 60 values across your width, that could be: `width/60`). *If the incoming points are inconsistent, then you'll need to translate by the width difference between the incoming points is in order to scroll the graph by an appropriate amount.*

The snippet below shows your chart assuming a constant rate of data input (I've also applied a transition to the x axis so it scrolls and doesn't jump):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>
    <svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    var n = 40,
        random = d3.randomUniform(0, 1),
        readings = [],
        currentReadings = [],
        duration = 1000,
        now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);
        startTime = new Date();
    
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([now - 60000, now])
        .range([0, width]);
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(data) { return xScale(data.time); })
        .y(function(data) { return yScale(data.hr); })
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);
    
    g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
    
    var xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).
          ticks(3));
    
    var yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    
    var path = g.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("path")
        .datum(currentReadings)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .on("start", tick);
    
    
    function tick() {

        now = new Date();
        
        // update the x axis domain and slide left
        xScale.domain([now - 60000, now]);
        
       // transition the axis:
       xAxisGroup.transition().duration(1000).ease(d3.easeLinear).call(xAxis);
       
       // generate new random reading
        reading = {time: new Date(), hr: random()};
    
        // Push the new reading onto readings and currentReadings
        readings.push(reading);
        currentReadings.push(reading);

        // Remove readings not within graph period
        for (var i=0; i<currentReadings.length; i++) {
          if (now - currentReadings[i].time > 60000)
            currentReadings.shift();
          else
            break;
        }
    
        // Redraw the line.
        d3.select(this)
            .datum(currentReadings)
            .attr("d", line(currentReadings))
            .attr("transform", null);

        // Slide it to the left.
        d3.active(this)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + -width/60 + ",0)") // transition based on distance between each data point.
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .on("start", tick);
    
    }
    
    
    
    </script>
```

*The jumpiness of the leading part of the chart is do to the easing and corrections to the easing made once the next point is generated*